# React / Meteor / Flowrouter: Passing data

Tags: url, reactjs, flow-router

I have been trying to figure out a way of using the data given through flowrouters routing parameter with reactjs.

What i am trying achieve is that when the user creates a farm with certain attributes and inserts that data into mongo collection, then in a another view i could update the values. so i would need to somehow to get the users _id for example, passed into this update view.

Currently i have this code as follows:

```
FlowRouter.route("/serviceplan/general/basic/:postId",{

name: "BasicInformation",
action(params){
    renderTestLayout(<BasicInfo params={params}/>);
}});
```

The view code:

```
BasicInfo = React.createClass({

 propTypes: {

     params: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
 },

mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

getMeteorData(){
    return{
        owner: Farms.findOne({farmname: this.props.params.postId})

    }
},

updateFarm(){
    console.log("updated!");
},

render(){

    console.log(this.data.owner);
    console.log(this.data.owner.address);

    return( 
        <div>

            <div className="col-sm-4">
            <h1>Basic information</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.updateFarm}>
                <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" ref="fname" className="form-control" defaultValue=""/><br></br>

                <label>Address:</label>
                <input type="text" ref="address" className="form-control" defaultValue=""/><br></br>

                <label>Postalcode:</label>
                <input type="text" ref="postalcode" className="form-control" defaultValue=""/><br></br>

                <label>Area:</label>
                <input type="text" ref="municipality" className="form-control"defaultValue=""/><br></br>

                <input type="submit" value="Update" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.updateFarm}/>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The problem here is when i am redirected to this BasicInfo component view the data works fine with props. but when i try to submit the changes, the page reloads and the app crashes. And its probably because the prop value is null since it has not been given to this component.

What would be the solution so i would get the postId value from the url with every refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why the app was crashing and solution.

I was trying to access data which didn't exist.

```
if(this.data.owner){

        farmname = this.data.owner.farmname;
        address = this.data.owner.address;
        postalcode = this.data.owner.postalcode;
        municipality = this.data.owner.municipality;
        region = this.data.owner.municipality;
```

Working solution is to check if the mongo data object is not null before accessing it.